What do pilots do if they *really* need to go to the toilet in critical parts of the flight?
This question is a silly one, but I would like to ask anyway. What will pilots do if one of them really must use the bathroom in critical parts of the flight like when landing? I mean, like really need to go, probably because of some spoiled food or a minor medical condition. Are there any official guidelines (probably not) or typical actions to reduce the risks of flying with only one pilot? Any thought on this? I'll appreciate any answer, preferably from a pilot's first-hand experience.

Is this *really* about aviation?!

@Jamiec Yeah, why not? And why the downvotes?

So many possible duplicates. Hopefully someone will pick one and VtC as dupe.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 I lean towards agreeing with you, we get so much aerodynamics and engineering stuff on aviation stack exchange, so why not something like this.

Minor medical condition: the pilot should be prepared: diaper or extra wears in bag, Else I would not consider it minor (for a pilot).

Are you sure? And do you thing you will embarrassed by medical conditions? Maybe the first week. There are various medical conditions which requires it, and you probably never noticed (but probably it requires some medical check). If it happens just one every few years is something, else ... really you should plan. Planing is an important bahaviour which should be in nature in every commercial pilots.

Any comment from downvoters? Please tell me where I can improve my post. Thanks in advance.

Please, anyone tell me where I can improve? If there's anything I can improve, please tell me. Thanks.

Pilots typically plan ahead to avoid needing a toilet break during critical phases of flight, such as landing or takeoff. For example, I fly the Boeing 737, and aim to use the bathroom around 300 nautical miles before the top of descent (If I predict I will need to use it before landing). This timing is usually about 50 minutes to an hour before landing, giving me ample time to return to the flight deck, conduct descent and approach planning, and complete any necessary briefings.
However, in the event of an urgent need due to something like spoiled food or a minor medical condition, the situation could potentially escalate to what is considered "Pilot Incapacitation." Pilot Incapacitation is a scenario covered by various procedures and drills, both for the flight crew and cabin crew. Each airline has its own set of protocols for handling such situations. If the incapacitation is severe enough that the flight effectively becomes a single-pilot operation, the remaining pilot would most likely declare an emergency ("Mayday") over the radio to prioritise the flight's safe completion.

Some specifics from your question:

What will pilots do if one of them really must use the bathroom in critical
parts of the flight like when landing?

If they sense a bad bout of something, they may try and let the other pilot know before commencing the approach, then use the toilet. If they have commenced the approach, they will probably break the approach off, discontinue, hold somewhere, so that pilot can use the toilet. If they still feel bad, then it will go down the pilot incapacitation procedures.

Are there any official guidelines (probably not) or typical actions to
reduce the risks of flying with only one pilot?

During our Human Performance and Limitations pilot theory studies, we are taught that during long haul operations, pilots will eat different meals to avoid both pilots getting the same food poisoning. I am not a long haul pilot so can't speak to this, but there is discussion about this in various places: simple flying and other questions. Most short haul pilots (Europe at least) will not be provided any food on the aircraft by the company.
The Company's Operations Manual 1 would typically state that pilots must report in a "fit" state for duty, which mitigates the risk of flying with a pre-existing medical illness.
1: Citing regulations like: CAT.GEN.MPA.100, 170, 175 (EASA) or 14 CFR 91.3, 121.533, 121.580, 91.13 (FAA)

Thanks for your great answer! A pilot stuck in the bathroom isn't what I would normally call an "incapacitation", though. Still, your answer is helpful and informative. I upvoted it, BTW.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 "Pilot incapacitation refers to the inability of a pilot to perform their flight duties due to a sudden medical or psychological condition, which may render them either partially or completely unfit to operate the aircraft." EASA, Safety Information Bulletin (SIB) No. 2020-03.

OK, thanks for the clarification. I mistaken "incapacitation" for "passing-out". Sorry about that.

Oh, sorry for not accepting your answer earlier. I was busy with other things and other posts the last few days, and originally I was waiting for possibly more answers. I always wait a few days before accepting an answer, even if it's superb. That's the case here. Again, thanks for the great answer!
